# javascript validation for dates takes string for comparison

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

Sometime back i had asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416922/javascript-to-validate-start-date-and-end-date-in-asp-net) in SO as to how to validate startdate < enddate.

The JS that i had written is as below;

```
function DateValidation(startDate, endDate) {
                if (startDate != ' ' && endDate != ' ') 
                {
                    var stdate = Date.parse(startDate);
                    var enddate = Date.parse(endDate);
                    if (stdate > enddate) 
                    {
                        alert('Start date cannot be greater than end date!');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else 
                {
                    return true;
                }
               }
            }
```

The function gets called on the click of the submit button. It is register as;

```
OnClientClick="javascript: return DateValidation(window.document.getElementById('txtStartDate').value,window.document.getElementById('txtEndDate').value);"
```

Now assume that start date is October 4 2011 (04/10/2011) and end date is December 2 2011 (02/12/2011). In this case the alert should NOT get fired but it still gets fired up (because 04 > 02).

What mistake am i making here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your startDate & endDate parameters should be in mm/dd/yyyy format. But you provided them as dd/mm/yyyy format, so the unexpected thing occured.

I've faced this kinda probs B4. If your website's clients are all about to type in date time in format "dd/mm/yyyy", so you need a "correctDate()" function to replace date part with month part in the input-date-string.

The function may look like this :

```
function correctDate(D){
       var D=D.split('/');
       return D[1]+'/'+D[0]+'/'+D[2]
}
//input :  2/10/2011 , output :  10/2/2011
```

And in the DateValidation() function, you can use it like this:

```
....
      var stdate = Date.parse( correctDate(startDate) );
      var enddate = Date.parse( correctDate(endDate) );
      if (stdate > enddate){
....
```

Comment: But that would change the date as a whole. In your e.g,. 2/10 is Oct 2 which would change to Feb 10??

Comment: plus looking to my question, where would i call the correctDate function?

Comment: As I said in the answer, "If your website's clients are all about to type in date time in format "dd/mm/yyyy", so, you can use my method. How can you check the value : 2/10/2011 if you don't know the user means "2" is the "2nd" or "Feb" ? Is this value is valid compared to "5/5/2011" ???

Comment: You can use the "correctDate" function inside your DateValidation function. As in my answer: "...var stdate = Date.parse( correctDate(startDate) );...."

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = Date.parse("Jul 8, 2005");
document.write(d);
</script>
```

The output of the code above will be: 1120773600000

So your reasoning cannot be right. Try to alert the stdate and enddate after parsing. Something is happening there.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that you are making is that `Date.parse` interprets xx/xx/xxxx formatted strings as U.S. style dates with the month first.  `04/10/2011` is taken as April 10, not October 4.

Here is a transcript:

```
> var startDate = '04/10/2011';var stdate = Date.parse(startDate)
> startDate
04/10/2011
> stdate
1302418800000
> var endDate = '02/12/2011';var enddate = Date.parse(endDate);
> endDate
02/12/2011
> enddate
1297497600000
> stdate > enddate
true
```

IMHO you should avoid ambiguous date formats like this.  If date strings are to be used, force users to enter ISO8601 (yyyy/MM/dd) formatted text.

There is decent support for ISO8601 in ECMAScript 5 browsers.  Also see the Date.js library.  Or also [this SO question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479714/does-javascript-ecmascript3-support-iso8601-date-parsing).

**ADDENDUM**

The **built-in** `Date.parse` function is [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).  You can see it does not support DD/MM/YYYY.  While an evil programmer could accept a string in the form DD/MM/YYYY and use `substring` and `concat` (or regexes) to rewrite in an acceptable format for `Date.parse`, I'll assume you are not an evil programmer.

The proper solution is to use a date parser that accepts *format strings*.  For JavaScript, one such library is [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/).  It will allow you to write the following:

```
Date.parseExact("20/04/2011", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

and get the date object corresponding to April 20, 2011.

Comment: What would you like to do?  By "correct" do you mean you want people to enter DD/MM/YYYY?  Or can you accept other formats?  I can add to my answer; let me know which way you want to go.

Comment: I want date format to be keep as it is 04/10 should be 4th october and not 10th April

Comment: there is nothing like Date.parseExact in Javascript

Comment: @Xorpower, `Date.parseExact` comes from the Date.js library cited in the answer.  If you do not want to use a third-party library for some reason you are free to muck around with the string and build the date yourself.  This is doable with regexes as I mentioned but IMHO this is a hack.  If you are doing any serious date processing you should use a library, and Date.js is fairly well-known.